# Simple print() statement fails while printing a list: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters …

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have a function that wraps another function. (The wrapped function makes an ssh call via paramiko, but that's probably not important here.) The wrapped function seems to be returning a list, but when I try to print it, the code fails with `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4843-4844: ordinal not in range(128)`

The code:

```
tracelog = sys.stdout

def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    global tracelog
    print("Entering my_shell_func()", file=tracelog)
    rval = my_shell_func(*args, **kwargs)
    print("Exited   my_shell_func()", file=tracelog)
    print("  type(rval) =", type(rval), file=tracelog)
    print(rval, file=tracelog)
    return rval
```

The last print() statement failed with this error:

```
 Entering my_shell_func()
 Exited   my_shell_func()
   type(rval) = <class 'list'>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  …
  File "./mytest", line 41, in wrapper
    print(rval, file=tracelog)
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4843-4844: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It takes me about an hour to get to this failure point, so each test comes at significant cost. I still don't know what was in that list that made print() so unhappy.

Is there a way to get print() to print absolutely anything, no questions asked?

For now, I've wrapped that final print() statement with `try:…except:` and a message that says "sorry, can't print the output of this function, pressing on", which gets me unstuck, but is less than ideal.

Comment: sounds like your script isn't running with `LANG` set. try with `LANG=C.UTF-8`

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `global` statement if you want to *access* a global variable. You only need it if you think have to assign to a global variable from within a function or class.

Comment: My code is running inside of someone else's test environment, so I'm not sure if it's kosher to set LANG from inside my code. Still, I might as well give it a try to see if I learn anything. I *had* tried setting `tracelog = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)`, but Python3 didn't like that one bit.